# SpriteKit Keyboard Observer

Tags: macos, sprite-kit, observer-pattern, keyboard-events

I have currently been using delegation and an SKView custom class to monitor key presses in my OS X SpriteKit game. I need to employ multiple delegates for my keyboard monitoring class, which I know is not possible, but it is possible through using observers. How can this be accomplished? Here's my code using the delegation pattern:

**CustomSKView.h**

```c
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>

@protocol KeyPressedDelegate;

@interface CustomSKView : SKView

@property (weak) id <KeyPressedDelegate> delegate;

@end

@protocol KeyPressedDelegate

- (void) upArrowPressed;
- (void) downArrowPressed;

@end
```

**CustomSKView.m**

```c
#import "CustomSKView.h"

@implementation CustomSKView:SKView {
    // Add instance variables here

}

- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    if (self) {
        // Allocate and initialize your instance variables here

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) keyDown:(NSEvent *)theEvent {
    // Add code to handle a key down event here
    if (self.delegate) {
        switch (theEvent.keyCode) {
            case 126: {
                NSLog(@"delegate = %@", [self delegate]);
                [self.delegate upArrowPressed];
                break;
            }
            case 125:
                [self.delegate downArrowPressed];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

**GameScene.h**

```c
#import <SpriteKit/SpriteKit.h>
#import "CustomSKView.h"

@interface GameScene : SKScene <KeyPressedDelegate>

@end
```

**GameScene.m**

```c
#import "GameScene.h"

@implementation GameScene

-(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {
    ((CustomSKView *)view).delegate = self;
}

- (void) upArrowPressed {
    NSLog(@"Up Arrow Pressed");
}
- (void) downArrowPressed {
    NSLog(@"Down Arrow Pressed");
}

@end
```

Comment: Why do you think multiple delegates isn't possible? There's nothing preventing you from making an array of delegates.

Comment: That's just what I've read from many other posts. Ok, so going with the array idea, I would have to create an array in the `CustomSKView` class, then add each scene or any other object to it in their respective classes correct? From there, in the `CustomSKView` class I would run a loop notifying all of the delegates right?

Comment: Yea you'd have an array of delegates, and each time something wants to be a delegate, you add it to the array. Then when you want to call a delegate method, you do a for loop and call it on all the delegates. I'm not saying this is advisable, I just wanted to point out that it is possible :)

Comment: Lol...um, ok. If it's not advisable, what is the preferred method? That makes sense though :)

Comment: Probably `NSNotificationCenter`, what you were thinking of using. There are lots of good tutorials out there. Basically you will post a notifications with a name, and any class who is observing notifications with that name will call a method and do their thing.

Comment: Yeah, I've seen some tutorials out there, but I'm not clear on all of the details. I understand the concept overall, but like I said, not enough to implement the code with my project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for `NSNotificationCenter`. To add an object as an observer, use the following:

```c
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(keyPressed:)
                                             name:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"
                                           object:nil];
```

This causes that object to observe notifications with the name `@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"`. To post a notification with that name and attach the keyCode for the key that was pressed, call this:

```c
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"KeyPressedNotificationKey"
                                                    object:nil
                                                  userInfo:@{@"keyCode" : @(event.keyCode)];
```

When you post the notification, any observers will call the method associated with the observer. You can get the keyCode from the `userInfo` dictionary you attached when you posted the notification. In this case, the method with this signature will be called:

```c
- (void)keyPressed:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSNumber *keyCodeObject = notification.userInfo[@"keyCode"];
    NSInteger keyCode = keyCodeObject.integerValue;
    // Do your thing
}
```

There is one catch to this. You need to remove the object as an observer as soon as it is done observing. If you deallocate an object without removing the observer, then post the notification, it'll still try to call the method on your non-existent object and crash. Use the following code to remove the object as an observer:

```c
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:@"NotificationNameKey"
                                              object:nil];
```

Comment: For the first part where I'm adding an observer, since it will have a single selector should I add an observer for each key that's typed? If you take a look at the code I have up top, each key calls a separate method for the delegate.

Comment: No, use one notificaiton and pass the key code as an NSNumber as the object property on the notification.

Comment: Oh I take that back, you will need to use the user info dictionary. I'll edit my answer with an example.

Comment: @02fentym I edited the answer to make it more relevant to your scenario. I hope that helps.

Comment: Awesome, it worked. So essentially I'll have a super large switch block dealing with each case then. What is the benefit of this over just having each class use the `keyUp` and/or `keyDown` methods then?

Comment: Well I guess if you wanted to make an optional delegate method for every single key that could be pressed and then have your delegates implement only what they need it could be fine. But then you will have to call the specific delegate method for each keycode instead of just calling the one simple delegate method and passing the keycode. It's really up to you the design choice you want to make. There wouldn't be any performance difference, I think it's just more standard to say "I pressed a key, here is is", rather than 40 methods each saying "I pressed this specific key"

Comment: That's the whole point of method arguments. So you don't have to make a method for every possible scenario.